# Using Report Server Project Wizard (SSDT) in Visual Studio to run a query against each database

Tags: sql-server

I need to run the query below in Report Server Project Wizard (SSDT) in Visual Studio to export the data given to an Excel/PDF. This query repeats for all DBs in the instance, however, it is only running for 1 DB when using Report Server Project Wizard. When running through SSMS it is running successfully and giving data for all DBs. What can be used instead of sp_MSforeachdb when using Report Server Project Wizard since there in no option in Report Server Project Wizard to do query for all DBs.

```
use master
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 'use ? 
if DB_ID("?")>4 
select DB_NAME() as ''Database_Name'',name as ''DB_user'',type_desc,default_schema_name,create_date 
from sys.database_principals 
where type!=''C'' and type!=''R''' 
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Comment: Create a temp table/variable and insert to results of each into that. Then SELECT from that table to return the results for all databases in a single resultset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results from each call to `sp_MSforeachdb` will need to be persisted into a temp table.  After this perform a final `SELECT` to return the results for all databases as done in the example below using a local temp table.  While it's likely that the order of the rows in the table will be preserved from the inserts, this is not guaranteed without an explicit `ORDER BY`.  Assuming you are going to display the results ordered by database, this can be done as follows.

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 

SELECT @command = 'use ? 
if DB_ID("?")>4 
select DB_NAME() as ''Database_Name'',name as ''DB_user'',type_desc,default_schema_name,create_date 
from sys.database_principals 
where type!=''C'' and type!=''R''' 

IF (OBJECT_ID(N'TEMPDB.DBO.#TEMP') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #TEMP
END

CREATE TABLE #TEMP 
(
DatabaseName VARCHAR(50), 
DB_User VARCHAR(50),
TypeDesc VARCHAR(25),
DefaultSchemaName VARCHAR(50),
CreateDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command

SELECT 
    DatabaseName
    DB_User,
    TypeDesc,
    DefaultSchemaName,
    CreateDate
FROM #TEMP
ORDER BY DatabaseName
```